# Interial Momentium Question

Tags: energy-conservation, rotational-kinematics, kinetic-theory

I had a question for my Physics 101 class and was wondering if anyone could share some insights.

The question was stated as follows.

> A pottery wheel of radius 0.5 m and mass 15 kg rotates anticlockwise on a horizontal
>   plane at an angular speed of 38.2rpm. A lump of clay of mass 2 kg is dropped onto the
>   wheel at a distant 0.4m from the rotation axis.
>
> a. Determine the angular speed (in rad/s) of the wheel and the piece of clay after
>   it is dropped onto the wheel.
>
> b. Calculate the rotational kinetic energy of the system before and after the
>   collision and determine whether it is conserved? Explain this result

I solved the problem, but wasn't convinced about the given answer for the drop in rotational kinetic energy (part b).

My assumption was that dropping the clay on the disk would shift the center of momentum, and (for complicated reasons) generate a little lateral velocity.  I thought this was that is where the lost energy would have gone (as the disk is fixed it would be lost to friction).

The official answer however was that the energy is lost due to deformation of the clay in the collision.  I know the Ug energy would be lost this way, but I was surprised about so much rotational kinetic energy (4J) being lost in the collision as well.

Just wondering if anyone can confirm this for me.  I've seen a few other sources say the same thing about it being lost due to the collision.  Am I right in thinking if the disk wasn't fixed it would start to move after the collision?  And with how much energy?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose instead of dropping the lump of clay onto the disk you pressed on it with your hand:

[image: Press with hand]

This is going to produce a force $\mu F$ on the disk and therefore a torque $\mu Fr$ and as a result it will slow the disk down. The energy is dissipated as friction (your fingertip will get hot!).

Basically the same thing happens when you drop the lump of clay onto the disk. The clay can't be accelerated instantly because that would take and infinite force so for some short time after the clay first touches the disk there will be a velocity difference between the disk and the centre of mass of the clay.

If the clay were a rigid object there would be some sliding between the clay and the disk, just as there is between the disk and your finger in the diagram above. The sliding would dissipate energy as friction.

However we generally assume the clay is sticky and the thin layer of clay nearest the disk sticks to it and immediately acquires the speed of the disk. That means the only way for the velocity difference to be accomodated is if the disk deforms so the bit of the clay in contact with the disk moves at a different speed to the centre of mass. In this case the missing energy is lost in plastically deforming the clay, just as the answer to the question says.

It's tempting to ask how the clay knows to deform just enough to dissipate exactly the missing energy, but this is looking at the problem from the wrong end. The missing energy goes into deforming the clay and it deforms the clay until it's all used up.

If the axle weren't fixed then yes the disk would move when the clay touched it. Imagine doing the experiment with your finger again. When you press on the disk the disk is going to start rotating around your finger.  However calculating how fast the disk would move would [fall into our homework category](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange).